# "High-voltage" or "high voltage"

Tags: hyphenation

I don't understand whether I need to use hyphenation in "high-voltage". In scientific literature I see it being used interchangeably. Could anyone help me with this?

Here are some examples (I didn't use hyphens since I don't know if they should be there):

1. "High voltage equipment was used in the experiment".
2. "High voltage pulse is generated by neon-sign transformer."
3. "High voltage is necessary to cause dielectric breakdown."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a hyphen is included when you use a compound term as an adjective. So yes for #1 and no for #3. #2 isn't grammatical but would need a hyphen if you said "A high-voltage..."

This rule is broken a lot, though, so I don't think most people would care if you left out all hyphens.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining hyphenation and correcting #2.

Comment: Of course you could also fix #2 by changing it to “High-voltage pulses are generated ...”.

Comment: Please don't give answers to obviously off-topic questions. This lacks any research, and has essentially been answered before on ELU on more than one occasion. Repeats clutter the site.